# Can a function cease to decrease even at a non-critical point?

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

It was written in a paper I was reading that it might happen that for a minimization problem that the value of the function cease to decrease, but it is not guaranteed to converge to a stable point.

The objective to be minimized was approximating tensors, and the method used was alternating least squared method. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the optimization algorithm, if only the gradient of the cost function is taken into account, you can get stuck in a saddle point. For this $\nabla f = 0$, but the solution is not a stable point, Consider the situation

$$
f(x) = x^3
$$

Clearly $df(0)/dx = 0$, but $x=0$ is not a stable point of $f$.

[image]